# Numpy is installed but still get the error "No module named numpy"

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to run a python script which needs `numpy` module ,when I try to install it,it shows it is already present, when I run `import numpy`it throws the error `ImportError: No module named numpy`,any guidance on what is wrong?

```
[username@machine build]$ pip install numpy
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages
```

Below command shows numpy is not installed

```
[username@machine build]$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Feb 22 2017, 20:16:44) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.version)
2.7.12 (default, Feb 22 2017, 20:16:44) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)]
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Comment: pip is using python2.6 whereas your python is python2.7. Try installing the pip corresponding to your python version.

Comment: how to install pip corresponding to python version?I installed using `sudo yum install python-pip`,how should I change this command to install for python2.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Linux then use `python2.7 -m pip install numpy`

Answer (score -1):

For python version 2.7 use `python2.7 -m pip install numpy`

Alternatively, on Windows under bash use `py -2.7 -m pip install numpy`